# Trying to sort a vector of elements in R

Tags: r

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I was trying to build bubble sort mechanism on a given vector using R, but it throws me an error. v[1] refers to first element of v i.e 6.

```
v <- c(6,2,5,8)
c <- 1
n <- length(v)
   while(c <- n){
     if(v[c + 1] < v[c]){
      v[c] <- v[c] + v[c+1]
      v[c+1] <- v[c] - v[c+1]
      v[c] <- v[c] - v[c+1]
      c <- c + 1
      }else{
      c <- c + 1
   }
  return(v)
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: copy and paste the error that you're getting into your question above

Answer (score 1):

A  syntax error I found from googling the syntax of R:
in your while loop you say `(c <- n)`. This should be `(c <= n)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
sort(v)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's been a [long] while since I've programmed a bubble sort but I can still remember it well. There are several ways to implement it, here's one.

```
changed <- TRUE
while(changed){
    changed <- FALSE
    for(i in seq_along(v)[-length(v)]){
        if(v[i] > v[i + 1]){
            v[i] <- v[i] + v[i + 1]
            v[i + 1] <- v[i] - v[i + 1]
            v[i] <- v[i] - v[i + 1]
            changed <- TRUE
        }
    }
}

v
[1] 2 5 6 8
```

As for your routine, apart from what Jordy Brinks said, there's also the fact that your `while` loop would only do one pass through the vector, giving you a O(n) sort! The algorithm is wrong...
And you shouldn't put `c <- c + 1` on both branches of the `if/else` statement, put it right after it.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I fixed some of it and get a result but also an error.

Comment: OK! so, its doing what I want it to do i.e sort the elements in a vector but R throws an error for me. How to get rid of the error?

Comment: When it gives the error, you should print the value of `i`, not of `v`. `print(i)` outputs `[1] 8`. So `i + 1` is 9, and `v[9]` "doesn't" exist. I used the quotes because as far as `R`is concerned it does exist, but it's `NULL`. So the `if` condition is `NULL <= n` which is of **length zero** and a `TRUE/FALSE` is expected..